# TECSniffTextEncoding always says UTF-8

Tags: macos, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

How do I get `TECSniffTextEncoding` to distinguish between UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32? I'm trying to use it to determine the encoding of a text file, but it always returns UTF-8, even for files that are actually UTF-16 and UTF-32 (I'm trying both big and little endian).

I've tried to make sure I'm giving sufficiently large numbers for the maximum error and feature count, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. In fact, in every case there is a surprisingly large number of errors even for the correct encoding.

I created the files by saving them with TextEdit and specifying the encoding. I verified them by opening them in TextWrangler.

Here's the main code:
https://github.com/Uncommon/Xit/blob/7b2251d9b5f96098317dd7ab02b6bc43a516953b/Xit/NSData%2BEncoding.m

Here's the commit with the unit test and test files:
https://github.com/Uncommon/Xit/commit/7b2251d9b5f96098317dd7ab02b6bc43a516953b

Comment: `TECSniffTextEncoding` doesn't return a single encoding, it returns a list of probable encodings. Do the files contain invalid UTF-8 bytes? Do they contain a BOM or UTF-16/32-specific features?

Comment: I'm using the first one in the list as the answer, but it's always UTF-8. And yes, some of the test files have BOMs.

Comment: Only one of the test files has a BOM, and the "utf32le" file is encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Really? So much for trusting TextEdit.